# Designing Session Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I am designing and implementing a loan management system. One of the the functional requirements is

**- calculate interest daily, and compounded monthly.**

I want to implement this requirement using session beans. How best can I design the session beans? 
I have Account and Interest entities. The Interest entity contains interest settings of the Account entity. I have tried to implement the functional requirement in the following DayInterest session bean to provide a better understanding of what I want to achieve.

```
package com.fsm.dayend;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import com.fsm.account.AccountFacade;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import com.fsm.account.Account;

/**
 *
 * @author Fact
 */
@Stateless
public class DayInterest implements DayInterestLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.fsm_DebtorsAccounts-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @EJB
    AccountFacade accountFacade;

    private Account account;

    public DayInterest() {
    }

    public DayInterest(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }



    public void updateInterest(){
        double interestAccrued= account.getBalance()*account.getInterest().getRate()* 1/360;
        account.getInterest().setAccrued(account.getInterest().getAccrued()+interestAccrued);
        accountFacade.edit(account);
    } 



}
```

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: Is this the best way to implement the problem?